# LayoutInflater Mono for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, layout-inflater

I want to create programatically my relativeLayout using LayouInflater but it throws an error on AddView method, heres is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:id="@+id/relativeAgedSummary"     
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

ViewGroup relativeAgedSummary=FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.relativeAgedSummary);
View view = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
                                Resource.Layout.aged_summary_list_item, 
                                relativeAgedSummary, false);    

for (int i = 0; i < agedValues.Count; i++) {
    var row = agedValues.ElementAt(i);
    if(row.Range  == 0 && row.IsTotal == false)
    {
        RelativeLayout rl = view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(
                                           Resource.Id.relativeLayoutAgedSummaryItem);
        rl.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.lightBlue); 
        if(contA==0)
        {
           TextView tv = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtAgedSummary); 
           tv.SetText(labelsAgedSummary[row.Range], TextView.BufferType.Normal);
           contA++;
        }           
        relativeAgedSummary.AddView(view);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error that it throws? http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: A fixed, but now i want to add more realtive layout, and it only appears one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean "it only appears one". If you are trying to add multiple instances to `relativeAgedSummary` then you will have to re-inflate the `aged_summary_list_item` each time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < agedValues.Count; i++)
{
    View view = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
                    Resource.Layout.aged_summary_list_item, 
                    relativeAgedSummary, false);

    var row = agedValues.ElementAt(i);

    // the logic here...

    relativeAgedSummary.AddView(view);
}
```

This is because you are trying to add the same object more than once. It will ignore the add. And then in the loop you modify the same item repeatedly, thus resulting in it looking like it added only the "last" item.