# Add view to Horizontal Scroll View from separate layout file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to add a list of cards into a scroll view, using A separate xml file as my layout.

However on button press I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I can add the text just fine without using the Card.xml layout, its when I use that as my layout that I get the error.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);



    Button buttonWhite = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);



    //On button click, loop though dealt hand of cards and add each to Scrollveiw using Card layout file
    buttonWhite.Click += delegate
    {

        HorizontalScrollView ScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.horizontalScrollView1);

        //create layout from Cardlayout file
        LinearLayout Test_card = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Layout.Card);

        //loopthough Players hand and use text to add to card layout then add layout with text to scrollview
        foreach (Card Test in p.hand)
        {


            //create new textview
            TextView Test_Text = new TextView(this);


            //set new textviews text value to card text
            Test_Text.Text = Test.text;

            //addview to layout
            Test_card.AddView(Test_Text);

        }

        //add layout to scrollview
        ScrollView.AddView(Test_card);


    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inflate the Card resource layout, it is not in your current context. So you should replace:

```
 LinearLayout Test_card = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Layout.Card);
```

with (Java):

```
LinearLayout Test_card = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(Resource.Layout.Card);
```

C# (maybe):

```
LinearLayout Test_card = (LinearLayout) this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
                Resource.Layout.Card ...);
```

Comment: getLayoutInflater is telling me it doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: This method (getLayoutInflater) is native (Java) for Activity context. See documentation here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Activity.LayoutInflater/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212197/how-to-get-a-layout-inflater-given-a-context

Comment: Another answer that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470687/layoutinflater-mono-for-android